# Adding bibliography to TOC with a proper number

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I would like to add my bibliography to the TOC. I did this with `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{2.2}Literature}` but it seems that the section number is seen only in TOC, not in the article, see:

[image]

Moreover, after adding the bibliography to the TOC, the numbering of the following subsections (the `Acronyms`) is damaged.

Here's MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[toc, acronym, numberedsection, section=subsection]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{cpu}{CPU}{Central Processing Unit}
\newacronym{isp}{ISP}{Internet Service Provider}
\newacronym{dss}{DSS}{Decision Support System}
\newacronym{aes}{AES}{Advanced Encryption Standard}

\begin{document}      

\tableofcontents

\section{A1}

\subsection{A1}

\gls{aes}

\subsection{A2}

\gls{cpu}, \gls{aes}

\subsection{A3}

\cite{whatisiot}

\section{B}
\subsection{B1}

\renewcommand\refname{Literature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{2.2}Literature}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybibfile}

\printglossaries 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{tocbibind}`, read the documentation please which other `ToC` - like entries should either go to the ToC or not

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to print bibliography under a `subsection` `Literature` and keep `\refname` empty. Something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[toc, acronym, numberedsection, section=subsection]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{cpu}{CPU}{Central Processing Unit}
\newacronym{isp}{ISP}{Internet Service Provider}
\newacronym{dss}{DSS}{Decision Support System}
\newacronym{aes}{AES}{Advanced Encryption Standard}

\begin{document}      

    \tableofcontents

    \section{A1}

    \subsection{A1}

    \gls{aes}

    \subsection{A2}

    \gls{cpu}, \gls{aes}

    \subsection{A3}

    \cite{whatisiot}

    \section{B}
    \subsection{B1}

    \renewcommand\refname{\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}}
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{2.2}Literature}
    \subsection{Literature}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{mybibfile}

    \printglossaries 

\end{document}
```

[image]